# LogStash JDBC input scheduling issue - is it possible to run query a minute after the previous query finished

Tags: jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I'm using the Jdbc input in LogStash to retrieve data from MS SQL database once in a minute.

Usually it works fine. But we know database performance is not very reliable thing and sometime it's takes longer than one minute to a query to return. Sometime event 5 minutes.

But the Jdbc scheduler still run a query once a minute so there situations when multiple queries run at the same time. This creates additional pressure on a database and after some time there are 20 almost same queries run at the same time.

I assume I'm not the first person which encounter this problem. I'm sure there is some way to make Jdbc to run next query a minute **after the previous** once is finished. Am I right?